# Drupal to Liferay Migration

Tags: drupal, migration, liferay

I want to migrate my existing Drupal sitea (about 600 pages) to Liferay. What will be the bestway? Do I perform DB to DB Migration? If yes, how it can be done?

Is there any solution provider who is giving this service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you'll have to determine how to structure the content in Liferay, I'd recommend going through the API - you'll need to create the appropriate pages, determine the layout you need for that page, position the content (e.g. navigation, web content, asset publisher, blog) on the page. This is highly depending on your existing drupal implementation and how you can make sense of your pages.

If you want to have some hints on how to use Liferay's API, my suggestion is to read up on the 7cogs sample code, e.g. in [two](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) blog [articles](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/part-ii-7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) by James Falkner.

Comment: It seems those articles were moved to https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs- and https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/part-ii-7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs- but I don't see concrete hints how to migrate a Drupal site to LifeRay

Comment: Indeed there's nothing concrete and ready to go - and if it was, by now it'd be outdated anyway. A big problem is that there are different concepts between the individual products, and on top of that, different usages of those concepts to map the features to business requirements. So you'd need to make sense of what's a page, an article, a headline, some dynamic reference to other content, static filler etc., and map that concept to the target system. This is independent of Drupal/Liferay, but applies to any migration of this kind with any software.